# jquery masked input

Tags: jquery, javascript

I was trying to mask a text field and took a look at http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Has anyone used this plugin before?

I am trying to mask a text field so that users are only able to enter some dollar amount to it.  dollar amount can be between 0 - 500000

Is that feasible through this plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Masked input plugin can only do fixed length fields.
It can also do partial inputs, but only on the end of the field.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to make a mask for a range will just annoy users.  Instead, use the blur event to check the range when the focus leaves the text field.

```
$('#yourinput').blur(function() {
  val dollarAmount = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (dollarAmount < 0) {
    $(this).val(0);
  } elseif (dollarAmount > 500000) {
    $(this).val(500000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've liked working with the masked input plugin as well, and was looking to create the same thing.  I agree with Aaron above that I don't believe the jBush Masked Input plugin currently supports it that I can find.  Although I think jBush has been looking at making this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-masked-input-plugin-direction

I've been looking around for the same thing.  So far the closest thing I found, which I'm settling for at the moment, is this alphanumeric plugin: http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

To address your question you can set it to allow numeric only, plus a few extrax (comma, decimal).

Answer (score 1):

All of the plugins I found have some annoyances or strange behavior (cursor jumps to end, text can't be selected using shift+arrow keys, etc), but this one has the least of these problems I could find:

https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

Sorry to dig up this old thread, but I ended up using this plugin, might be useful for someone stumbling on this thread (like me)